# How send response in Scala Play 2.0?

Tags: scala, playframework, request, response

I have two Play apps on localhost and some request between them. Bob send request to Alice look like oficial docs

```
 val respoonse = WS.url("http://localhost:8080/validatetoken").withQueryString("token" -> token).get()
respoonse.map {
  response => (response.json \ "access").asOpt[String].get match {
    case "grant" => true
    case "denied" => false
  }
}
```

But I have not any idea and cant find any examples about how send response from Alice. Maybe I am stupid but I hope that somebody help me.

Comment: I think you need to explain exactly what you want to achieve. It is very unclear what you are asking and how the snippet of code you've posted relates to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Alice app you have to define function:

```
def validatetoken(token :String) = Action {
// do your business here and build a json response YOUR_JSON
Ok(YOUR_JSON).as(JSON)
```

}

and add the following line to your routes:

```
GET        /validatetoken        controllers.Application.validatetoken(token:String)
```